Web version of flutter app won't display index.html page
I have created a flutter app on my Android device and it works fine there. However, when I try to run it on Chrome all I get is a blank screen.
I have not changed anything in the index.html file, it is just what was created by flutter ans VSCode.
I am using windows and VSCode to develope the app.
Here is my index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <!--
        If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
        href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

        The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
        it to work correctly.

        For more details:
        * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

        This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
        the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
      -->
      <!-- base href="./" -->
      <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">


      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
      <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

      <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="deal_diligence">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

      <!-- Favicon -->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

      <title>deal_diligence</title>
      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

      <script>
        // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
        const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
      </script>
      <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
      <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
          // Download main.dart.js
          _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
            serviceWorker: {
              serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
            },
            onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
              engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
                appRunner.runApp();
              });
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>

How do I get the index to show the login screen?
Thanks
I would like to see the login screen displayed on the screen.
UPDATE:
Here is the code from my main.dart file:
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FirebaseApi().initNotifications(); 

  runApp(const ProviderScope(
      child:
          DealDiligence())); // This allows the entire app to use River_Pod for state management
}

class DealDiligence extends StatelessWidget {
  const DealDiligence({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}


Are there any warning or errors displayed at the console? Also post a MRE and flutter version.

I am not on the dev machine right now but I have the latest version of flutter and there are not any error messages, just a blank screen. Thanks for your response.

Can't really tell much without some code. Try sharing minimal reproducible example.

The code I supplied is the code that is n ot working. I don't know what more you want to see. I am happy to provide more if you let me know what you are looking for. Thanks

That index.html is the code that was generated, right? I mean the flutter code from the main function until where this behavior happens. Don't have to share your actual code, something that is similar.

Yes, index.html was generated and I have not changed it. I added the code from main.dart as well.

Problem seems to be at Firebase.initializeApp(). When I commented it out, the rest of the app runs.

Sorry, I have been very busy. Ok, I will look at that. Thank you for your help.
